# Angular2 Form datepicker not detecting as touched as soon as it is focused

Tags: html, angular

Instant validation for datepicker in angular 2. As soon as the Date is entered it has to detect the min or max date. Right now after a click event it is detecting as touched.Is there anything else that has to be changed for it to detect.

```html
<form #Details1="ngForm">
   <div class="form-group" fxLayout="column" style="width:531px;">
      <md2-datepicker mdInput
                      id="rDate"
                      name="rDate"
                      [(ngModel)]="component.rDate"
                      #receivedDate="ngModel"
                      placeholder="rDate"
                      format = 'MM/dd/y'
                      min="minDate"
                      max="maxDate"
                      type="date"></md2-datepicker>
<md-error *ngIf="rDate.invalid && (rDate.dirty || rDate.touched)">Please select a valid R Date</md-error>
<md-error *ngIf="(rDate.hasError('md2DatepickerMin') || rDate.hasError('md2DatepickerMax'))">Year between 1800-2099</md-error>
</div>
</form>
```